# How to refresh recyclerView after changing data?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with RecyclerView. I need to refresh it after clicking a long click. I tried to play with notifyDataSetChanged() method. But nothing works. Here is my code. In current situation item removes from database right away. But I have to move to another activity and come back to see any UI changes. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
public class AlarmsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Alarm> alarmsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private AlarmRecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
    private AppDataBase db;
    private AlarmsDao alarmDao;
    private OnClickedRecyclerAdapter<Alarm> recyclerListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarms_activity);
        db = App.getInstance().getDataBase();
        alarmDao = db.AlarmDao();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerListener = new OnClickedRecyclerAdapter<Alarm>() {
            @Override
            public void onLongClicked(final Alarm data) {
                removeAlarm(data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClicked(Alarm data) {

            }
        };
        mAdapter = new AlarmRecyclerAdapter(alarmsList, recyclerListener);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getData();

    }

    public void getData(){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (Alarm alarm : alarmDao.getAll()){
                    alarmsList.add(alarm);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void removeAlarm(final Alarm alarm){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.e("xxx", "Long clicked");
                alarmDao.deleteAlarm(alarm);

            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

OnClickListener

```
public interface OnClickedRecyclerAdapter<Alarm> {
    void onLongClicked(Alarm data);
    void onClicked(Alarm data);
}
```

Adapter.

```
public class AlarmRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmViewHolder> {

    List<Alarm> alarms;
    OnClickedRecyclerAdapter listener;
    private AppDataBase db;
    private AlarmsDao alarmsDao;

    public AlarmRecyclerAdapter(List<Alarm> alarms, OnClickedRecyclerAdapter listener) {
        this.alarms = alarms;
        this.listener = listener;
        db = App.getInstance().getDataBase();
        alarmsDao = db.AlarmDao();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AlarmViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler, parent, false);
        return new AlarmViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Alarm alarm = alarms.get(position);
        holder.time.setText(alarm.getHour()+" : " + alarm.getMinute());
        holder.days.setText(alarm.getDays());
        holder.isOn.setChecked(alarm.isIs_on());
        holder.isOn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                Log.e("xxx", b + " ");
            }
        });
        holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onClicked(alarm);
            }
        });
        holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

                listener.onLongClicked(alarm);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return alarms.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide position in inside your interface methods and than call: `adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);` What is your `deleteAlarm` method do? Because you need to remove the `item` from the `list` as well.

Comment: Deletealarm removes object from database. I tried adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position), but it's not really helped. Recycler item blinks, but not disappear.

Comment: Are you removing item from the list as well?

Comment: @Yupi what do you mean? When I click long click it has to remove it from db and from recycler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        listener.onLongClicked(alarm);
        return true;
    }
});
```

To this:

```
holder.cardView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        listener.onLongClicked(alarm);
        alarms.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition()); //or alarms.remove(alarm);
        notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition()); //or notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
});
```

The problem is that you're removing the alarm from your database when you call `removeAlarm()` in your Activity, but you're not actually removing it from the `alarms` list in your Adapter. The change isn't being reflected because the data set never changes in your code. When you recreate your Activity, you pass the new database list into the Adapter, so it updates then.

I also recommend not doing this:

```
public void getData(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (Alarm alarm : alarmDao.getAll()){
                alarmsList.add(alarm);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

While `alarmsList` in your Activity and `alarms` are the same instance, and thus reflect the same additions and removals, there's no guarantee this logic will complete before the RecyclerView is inflated and the adapter attached. That means you could end up with missing data, especially on slower devices.

Unless you have an absolute ton of Alarms, there's no need to run that in a new Thread. You could just move that for-loop right above where you initialize the Adapter, and use the `addAll()` method:

```
alarmsList.addAll(alarmDuo.getAll());
mAdapter = //your assignment from your code
```

If you do need it to be async, attach the Adapter later, inside your Thread:

```
public void getData(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alarmsList.addAll(alarmDuo.getAll());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                mAdapter = new AlarmRecyclerAdapter(alarmsList, recyclerListener);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Remove the assignment, adapter setting and `notifyDataSetChanged()` calls from your `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarms_activity);
    db = App.getInstance().getDataBase();
    alarmDao = db.AlarmDao();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerListener = new OnClickedRecyclerAdapter<Alarm>() {
        @Override
        public void onLongClicked(final Alarm data) {
            removeAlarm(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClicked(Alarm data) {

        }
    };
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    getData();

}
```